# How can I get the newest version of google play services on an AVD?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services

I'm trying to develop an Android app that has a native Google Maps control. Seems simple enough, but unfortunately I've run into a lot of trouble setting it up.

I have very carefully followed the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map) multiple times with no success. Every time I try to load up my app, I get the message `<my app> won't run without Google Play services, which are not supported by your device`. I have confirmed in the settings that I do in fact have Google Play services on the device.

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall downloaded google services apk's, but abd does not allow me to uninstall it with the error `DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR`, I assume it is because I don't have root access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer to my own question. I made a dumb mistake...

In my manifest, I entered my api key where it says API_KEY: `android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` but it should just be API_KEY. Changing this, and using Google Play services 9 instead of 10 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your SDK and install the latest Google Play Services library under "Extras" section.  The AVD can be launched using "android" binary under your SDK tools folder.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. My SDK is updated and I've installed the Google Play services library as you mentioned. I'm still getting the same error unfortunately... I somehow got it to the point where the error now states that the app won't run if I don't update google play services. The android monitor shows: `Google Play services out of date. Requires 10084000 but found 9877030`